# AutoMapper Setting a boolean property as false while mapping

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am writing a `DeactivateUser` method for my Web API.

User.cs

```cs
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using TwitterCloneApp.Core.Interfaces;

namespace TwitterCloneApp.Core.Models
{
    public class User : IBaseEntity, ICreatedAt, IUpdatedAt, IDeletable
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string? Biography { get; set; }
        public string? ProfileImg { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
        public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
        public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Tweet>? Tweets { get; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Like>? Likes { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<User>? Followers { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<User>? Following { get; set; }
    }
}
```

IsActiveDto.cs

```cs
namespace TwitterCloneApp.DTO.Response.User
{
    public class IsActiveDto
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DeactivateUser method in my UserService.cs

```
public async Task DeactivateUserAsync(int userId)
        {
            string cacheKey = string.Format(ConstantCacheKeys.UserKey, userId);
            User user = null;
            if (await _cacheService.AnyAsync(cacheKey))
            {
                user = await _cacheService.GetAsync<User>(cacheKey);
            }
            else if (await _userRepository.AnyAsync(u => u.Id == userId))
            {
                user = await _userRepository.ActivateUserAsync(userId);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotFoundException($"UserId({userId}) not found!");
            }
            var isActiveDto = new IsActiveDto();
            _mapper.Map(isActiveDto, user);

            _userRepository.UpdateAsync(user);
            await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
        }
```

Mapping configuration for this method

```
CreateMap<User, IsActiveDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsActive, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => false));
```

I want to set `IsActive` property as false while mapping it. I don't want to map it manually. I want to use AutoMapper. Also can I create a new `IsActiveDto` with something like `BeforeMap`? I want to stick to Single Responsibility.

I checked official documentation and similar questions but couldn't find anything. You can send if you know.

Comment: *I want to set IsActive property as false while mapping it. I don't want to map it manually.* You mean you want to set the `IsActive` false for `User` or `IsActiveDto`. From your code, I don't see any reason why you try to map `user` to `IsActiveDto` and update `user` record in DB. It seems `isActiveDto` is unused and the mapping is unnecessary. Would be great if you can explain what you are trying to achieve especially for the AutoMapper mapping part.

Comment: @YongShun My thoughts exactly. Generally you would just change the value of `IsActive` in the User DTO and then save it...

Comment: @YongShun
I want to set IsActive property as false while mapping. I created an IsActiveDto to configure IsActive property only cause I am using it for activation, deactivation only. That's why I created a DTO. So I am asking if there is a way to set bool to false automatically while converting. This way I will stick to SIngle Responsibility. I did it this way but it doesn't work. I can do it this way: var isActiveDto = new IsActiveDto { IsActive = false }; _mapper.Map(isActiveDto, user); but I want to set it while mapping rather than creating an instance.

Comment: @JeffB Yes but what about S(ingle Responsibility)OLID?

Comment: @OnatEgeKaraman I think you are applying the concepts of SOLID incorrectly here. You don't need to break out the functionality of `IsActive` away from the user object. That is adding unnecessary layers of abstraction that will only come back to hurt you in the long run. Single responsibility simply means that a given class does one thing. IE, the user DTO does one thing, is a data sack for user information.

Comment: @JeffB Then what is a better approach? I am new to .NET and I just wanted to use AutoMapper. If it is not necessary, maybe just something like this:

        user.IsActive = true;

Comment: @OnatEgeKaraman Honestly if you are new to .net, I would recommend using Entity Framework and LinQ.
If you want to add the ability to disable a user, have an endpoint in a controller that accepts a userId. That controller will call a function that uses EF to select the user based on ID, flip the boolean, and save changes. Also, take a look at CQRS and MediatR. Separation of concerns is a useful tool.

Comment: @JeffB Then I guess it's better to use AutoMapper and DTOs with UpdateUser like controllers.

Comment: @OnatEgeKaraman Honesetly not sure why you are trying to use AutoMapper here. AutoMapper is for mapping data between objects that are of different types. Nothing in your above example has a need for AutoMapper.

Comment: @JeffB I will not use it here. I adjusted and set it with 
user.IsActive = true;  
_userRepository.UpdateAsync(user); I will use AutoMapper for updating user. UpdateUser controller will take an UpdateUserDto as parameter to specify what do we want to change. Then it will apply changes on User entity while mapping,

Comment: @OnatEgeKaramanq Generally your controller endpoint would expect a DTO called "UpdateUserRequest", just a tip on convention!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just got it better now. I know things but I have problem about how to have a better approach while implementing. :)